# Index strategy for entities with translation in a different table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

I have the following data structures:

```
Article: IdArticle, IdParentArticle, IdWebsite, Author, DateUpdated, Status, ...
ArticleTran: IdArticle, IdLanguage, Title, Content, ...
```

I need to build different queries on articles, taking into account that:
- there is always a current website (see column IdWebsite) and a language id (see column IdLanguage) to filter on
- in Article I can have stub articles (i.e. the article inherit data from his parent - see IdParentArticle column)
- if title or content is not available, then a fallback to default language should be made

Now I'm thinking what DB design and index strategy to choose:

**1/ Create a view vwArticles** that returns list of articles with full info, regarding or not the article is a stub

```
SELECT A.IdArticle, A.IdParentArticle, A.IdWebsite, ... 
FROM Article A      
WHERE A.IdParentArticle IS NULL    
UNION      
SELECT Stub.IdArticle, Stub.IdParentArticle, A.IdWebsite, ...   
FROM Article Stub
    INNER JOIN Article A ON A.IdArticle = Stub.IdParentArticle
WHERE Stub.IdParentArticle IS NOT NULL
```

**2/ Create a view vwArticlesTran** that contains article info + translated info:

```
SELECT
    A.IdArticle, A.IdParentArticle, A.IdWebsite,
    COALESCE(L.Title, LD.Title),
    COALESCE(L.Content, LD.Content),...
FROM
    vwArticles A
    LEFT JOIN ArticleTran L ON A.IdArticle = L.IdArticle
    -- fallback for default language
    LEFT JOIN ArticleTran LD ON A.IdArticle = LD.IdArticle AND LD.IdLanguage = 1
```

**3/ Primary Keys:**

```
PK Article: on column IdArticle, non-clustered
PK ArticleTran: on columns IdArticle + IdLanguage, clustered
```

**4/ Create the following indexes:**

```
IX_ArticleTran_IdArticle => for JOIN in vwArticles
IX_ArticleTran_Title => for search after title
IX_Article_DateUpdated - clustered => articles are usually ordered by DateUpdated DESC
```

Do you have any other suggestions about my proposal? Is anything that can be improved?
**Does it worth to create a covering index on ArticleLang?**